# Dell XPS 13 9300 Intel WiFi Not Working

Tags: debian, networking, linux-kernel, wifi, iwlwifi

The WiFi on my new Dell XPS 13 9300 refuses to work. Many solutions online that I found online involve downloading it on device... which I can't do because the WiFi is broken (the issue) and I don't have a USB-C to Ethernet adapter. I've downloaded the `firmware-iwlwifi_20210315-2~bpo10+1_all.deb` package from Debian's firmware repo using my Mac and put it on a USB stick, and then transferred it over to my device. I tried installing it both with `apt install` and `dpkg -i`. Both claim to be successful, but it still doesn't work. I then tried running `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi ; sudo modprobe iwlwifi`, still to no avail (no interface other than loopback is displayed when I run `ip a` and `ping 1.1.1.1` says that the network is unreachable).

I've seen some solutions that say to install a newer kernel, but they all involve accessing the internet from the device that's having the issues... If it's possible to download the kernel on a different device and move it over via USB, that would be nice.

I've also tried restarting the device. That doesn't work either.

I’ve considered the possibility that I need to select a network and enter a password, but since even the interface doesn’t show up I’m guessing that that’s not the issue.

Any ideas?

Note: before I installed Linux, Windows had working WiFi, so it doesn't seem like it's a hardware issue. I can't go back to test since I wiped Windows.

Comment: You need to give us more info directly by editing it in your question (NOT as a comment please).  What Linux flavor do you boot ?  Straight Debian ?  Some minor aspects of exactly how to bootstrap your WiFi/BT resource may depend on your version of Linux.  Also have a look at the excellent resources available for Arch linux at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_manager (if you use NetworkManager) and https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Wpa_supplicant if you want to know what wpa_supplicant can do for you.

Comment: Very often Archwikis can be used as the basis for understanding the nuts and bolts of how many services function on your Linux system, even when that system is not Arch linux. 

Please also include the output of `lspci -k` and of `ip link` and `dmesg | grep firmware` to see if some Wifi interface was created and firmware was correctly loaded at boot , etc.  Please include your response in a EDIT section at the end of your original post.

Comment: Please include **how** you installed `firmware-iwlwifi` in your post .
For a very downsized version of Archwiki on the subject, see: https://www.linuxsecrets.com/archlinux-wiki/wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration.html